# Remove unwanted characters from a string in table cell

Tags: reactjs, replace, cell, react-table

I have a React table (`react-table`) that takes in data from an api to populate the row cells. The data looks something like this:

```
const data = [{id: "6666", contact_id: "1", poc_id: "2", contact: "John Doe", 
               watersheds: "{12070104,12090301,12090401}"}, {id: "6667", contact_id: "2", 
               poc_id: "3", contact: "Sally Jones", watersheds: "{12070105,12090301}"}]
```

There could be more or less items depending on what the `API` request returns. My issue is that when the `Watershed` column is populated with the `watershed` data item, it includes the `{ ... }s`. I want it to return `12070104,12090301,12090401` in the cell, not `{12070104,12090301,12090401}`. I know I can use `replace` or some other method to remove and replace the unwanted `{ }s`:

```
data.map(item => (item.watersheds.replace(/{/gi, "").replace(/}/gi, "")))
```

or something similar, but since I adding the data to the table dynamically, I'm not sure how to remove the `{ }s` before they are displayed in the table? My table looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import makeData from './makeData'

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'ID',
        accessor: 'id',
      },
      {
        Header: 'CONTACT ID',
        accessor: 'contact_id',
      },
      {
        Header: 'POC ID',
        accessor: 'age',
      },
      {
        Header: 'NAME',
        accessor: 'contact',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Watersheds',
        accessor: 'watersheds',
      }
    ], []
  )

  //const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), [])
  const data = useMemo(() =>    [{id: "6666", contact_id: "1", poc_id: "2", contact: "John Doe", 
    watersheds: "{12070104,12090301,12090401}"}, {id: "6667", contact_id: "2", 
    poc_id: "3", contact: "Sally Jones", watersheds: "{12070105,12090301}"}])  

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a custom content for each cell . Instead of transforming the data before passing to the table . we can just transform the value before rendering .

```
 {
        Header: "Watersheds",
        accessor: "watersheds",
        Cell: (props) => {
          return <p>{props.value.replace(/{/gi, "").replace(/}/gi, "")}</p>;
        }
      }
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-paper-1po5l?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

In your `App` component, right before using `useMemo`, you can extract that array of objects to a separate varible, iterate over `watersheds` and replace them with the regex that you used above. After that you can pass it to `useMemo`.